# With git rebase, is there a way to reword commit messages in the git-rebase-todo using the default commands?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Suppose I run `git rebase -i HEAD~3`

```
pick 6b24464 foo
pick a681432 Foo
pick 8ccba08 foo foo

# Rebase 960c384..8ccba08 onto 960c384
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
```

I would like to reword commit messages directly from this file, rather than editing each commit message one at a time (as per usual with `reword`), like so:

```
reword 6b24464 foo bar
reword a681432 Foo Bar
reword 8ccba08 foo foo bar bar

# Rebase 960c384..8ccba08 onto 960c384
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
```

I had hoped that this could be done using just `reword` or `edit`, but I can't seem to figure out how (if even possible).  I've been able to achieve the same result with

```
x git cherry-pick 6b24464 && git commit -amend "foo bar"
```

However, this is more time consuming than I'd like for large rebases.  Any ideas?

Comment: Beware of a `git log` is during a reword of an interactive rebase: see "[`git rebase -i` shows wrong commit history after a rebase and force push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362522/6309)".  
Use Git 2.24+ (Q4 2019).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I do not believe that can be done, because when you do a `git rebase -i` you get only the first line of each commit message, not the full commit message.

As a convention, a commit message should have the first line be only a summary, and have more details about the change in the following lines. [Here's Linus Torvalds on how to write a proper commit message](https://github.com/torvalds/subsurface-for-dirk/blob/a48494d2fbed58c751e9b7e8fbff88582f9b2d02/README#L88-L115)

> *Also, please write good git commit messages.  A good commit message looks like this:*
>
> ```
> Header line: explain the commit in one line (use the imperative)
>
> Body of commit message is a few lines of text, explaining things
> in more detail, possibly giving some background about the issue
> being fixed, etc etc.
>
> The body of the commit message can be several paragraphs, and
> please do proper word-wrap and keep columns shorter than about
> 74 characters or so. That way "git log" will show things
> nicely even when it's indented.
>
> Make sure you explain your solution and why you're doing what you're
> doing, as opposed to describing what you're doing. Reviewers and your
> future self can read the patch, but might not understand why a
> particular solution was implemented.
>
> Reported-by: whoever-reported-it
> Signed-off-by: Your Name <youremail@yourhost.com>
> ```
>
> *where that header line really should be meaningful, and really should be just one line.  That header line is what is shown by tools like gitk and shortlog, and should summarize the change in one readable line of text, independently of the longer explanation. Please use verbs in the imperative in the commit message, as in `Fix bug that...`, `Add file/feature ...`, or `Make Subsurface...`*

So, even though you may have done only one line of message per commit, this is not what git is assuming, so it won't let you edit a commit message through a "one line per commit view".

Comment: That's a good point.  For this particular project, the summary commit messages were sufficient enough; I did not need full commit messages.  Looks like I forgot about it :)

Comment: Link is 404. Maybe include the solution here?

Comment: @thomas-b-in-bdx I rolled back your edit, because your edit was more a comment than an edit, and more importantly does not add to the answer (whether a multiline commit message is joined or not, you still cannot change it from the git rebase summary interface, only as it's stepping through the commits).

Answer (score 35):

You can probably use the `exec` option to achieve what you want.

Use an exec command similar to  `git commit --amend -m "this is the new message"`

You can either use that directly, or if you need more sophistication put it in an external script called `my_reword`.

```
#!/bin/sh
git commit --amend -m "$1"
```

Then add in the `exec` line wherever you want

```
pick 6b24464 foo
pick a681432 Foo
x my_reword "this is a new message"
pick 8ccba08 foo foo
```

Comment: I believe this is the best answer to the question.  It is true that you wouldn't want to use this method if you have a multi-line commit message, but it is very useful for quickly rewording one-liners.  Of couse, you must be sure that it is a one-line message to avoid removing stuff unintentionally.  This checking could be added to your custom my_reword just to ensure you don't accidentally throw a message away.

Comment: Related commit: https://github.com/git/git/commit/b12d3e904dc6deba7885d8528538de13e28128dd

Comment: Which commit are we rewording here? `a681432`, the one above?

Comment: @luckydonald - the one above yes

Answer (score 5):

added to my `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    w = "!reword() { git commit --amend -m \"$1\"; }; reword"
```

Then, `x git w "..."` just [like Andrew C proposed in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29200523/8119317).

As far as I know, people also usually name the alias `ca`...

Answer (score 1):

A refined solution, supporting a more natural syntax. Based on @AndrewC's work.

```
pick 7c88fde9
x reword Integrated database module
pick 23b35c34 fix this and that
x reword 'configuration reads ${HOME} now'
```

Save this script as "reword", executable, in the path:

```
#!/bin/sh
# In the git rebase todo list, directly reword commits. Save this script as "reword", executable, in the path.
# The message can be written literal or as one argument in double quotes. Use single quotes to not interpret ${HOME} `uname` etc.
git commit --amend -m "$*"
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't reword messages in the rebase TODO file.

The reason for this:  Git is applying the rebase from top to bottom.  The TODO file is only telling Git in what order to perform a rebase operation, and what its action is (squash, reword, use, fixup, etc).  It then relies on other mechanisms (like `commit`) to handle the rest.

If you have a lot of commits to reword, you're going to get a lot of prompts to edit the message, which *is what you should be expecting*; you're creating a new commit [regardless] with a new message, so Git should be asking you to enter it in while it's in the middle of processing the rebase operation.

I'd advise strongly against large rebase operations as it leads to this sort of mundane thing, and it has the risk of being more dangerous than it's worth.